How can I generalize my recurring business rules in .NET Core?
I am looking for a better approach for my recurring business rules. For example, when adding a category or adding a user, I check the existence of the same user every time.
Sample code:
var users = await _userService.GetAll();

if (users.Any(createUserDto.UserName))
{
    // ...
}

var products = await _productService.GetAll();

if (products.Any(createProductDto.ProductModelKey))
{
    // ...
}

From here, I want to generalize the same monotonous operations. For example, how can I do it with a method that I can use as attribute or with cross cutting?
What I want to do here is to put an attribute in the controller and create a method that will automatically query the relevant table, the column name of the table to be queried, and the query type (is it unique, has it been created before, etc.) from the enums, based on this attribute.

Let me get this straight. You fetch all users in the table in your db to check if a name already exists? That's really not how you are supposed to do that. That might work for 5 users and not even then.

There are different ways to do that. For example: unique constraints in your db table columns. If that's not enough or you want to fail early, then at least have the lookup done in the db, not client-side.

In fact, I'd move that into the xyzServices Create methods, so it can be part of a db transaction.

Thank you @Fildor, I will follow your approach. So are there any events that I can generalize with this kind of approach? Can you give me a couple of example scenarios?

Where do you want to apply these rules?  If it's in an edit/add form, then you should be doing this as part of the validation process.  If in the backend, then where do exceptions get reported?

I will do the scenario I mentioned in line with your suggestions. The approaches of the other friends who answered also provided a different perspective. Thank you all.

You can do it many ways, however as mentioned the validation needs to be done on the database side, not on the client side for many performance reasons.
Here are two ways to generalise it:

Using entity repository

If you choose this, it's mandatory that all of your entities must be able to do exactly the same thing, otherwise, this solution will go haywire fast.
You create a generic entity repository, which is capable of saving, loading, and manipulating your entities with your database.

Using validator class

In this case, you create a generic class which you will use to validate certain generic things for your classes. You inject this validator class to the other classes where you have to do the validation.
In both cases, you have to implement a specific interface for your classes that will allow you to enable these classes (one of them) to handle your class.
For example:
To be able to validate a user's existence, you will use email likely, but for content, you will use uuid. Somehow your generic class needs to know, and one easy way to provide this information is if your user and content class implements that specific interface which will define methods which allow you to get these data. Once you have it you wire it together the right way and you are done.
A poor concept (which is not the best implementation):
interface ICanValidated {
    string GetValidation(string typeIdentifier);
}

public class EntityValidator<T>
    where T : ICanValidated {
    
    private SqlConnection _database;
    
    public EntityValidator(SqlConnection database) {
        _database = database;
    }
    
    public bool ValidateIfExists(T entity) {
        using var command = _database.CreateCommand()
        
        command.CommandText = $"SELECT count(*) FROM {entity.GetValidation(\"table\")} WHERE {entity.GetValidation(\"field\")} = @field";
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@field", entity.GetValidation("value")));
        
        var count = command.Execute();
        
        return count > 0;
    }
}

Make sure that the table and field are safe, also not a user-editable thing, otherwise, you highly risking SQL injection!

You can try to use Remote Validation to check whether the new name/item has existed or not. Code like this:
To add additional parameter with Remote validation, you can use the AdditionalFields attribute. To validate two or more additional fields, provide them as a comma-delimited list, code like this:
public class MyClass
{
    [Remote("NameValidation", "Home", 
        AdditionalFields = "__RequestVerificationToken," + nameof(Id), 
        ErrorMessage = "exists", HttpMethod = "POST")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

The Home controller:
    public IActionResult RemoteValidationTest()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult RemoteValidationTest(MyClass myClass)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        return View();
    }

     
    [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    public IActionResult NameValidation(string Name, string Id)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
        {
            return Json($"Id is null.");
        }
        else if (Name=="AA" && Id == "A1")
        {
            return Json($"A user named {Name} already exists.");
        }
        return Json(true);
    }

Refer to the following links:
[Remote] attribute
Remote validation parameters?
Remote Validation in Razor Pages
